# How detect that find() function didn't find anything?

Tags: jquery, find

I want use `find` function to find elements but how I can detect that no thing found?

This is my code that not works properly and always return `true`:

```
if ($(this).find('img'))
    return true;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `.length`

```
if ($(this).find('img').length)
    return true;
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use .length, for example if your html is:

```
<div>
  <img src="" alt="" />
</div>
```

And your js/jquery is:

```
var test = $('div').find('img').length;
alert(test);
```

Having a div containing one image, test will alert 1.

In your case:

```
if($(this).find("img").length == 0){

// There is no image inside your selected element - Do something

}else{

// There is some image inside your selected element - Do something

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to use

```
$(this).find("img").length == 0
```

Even though it might seem a bit esoteric, .find() returns a jQuery Collection Object, which can contain pointers to 0 or more DOM elements. Your current code is only checking if a variable called $(this).find("img") is set.